# Validation on custom username and password using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In given code, I want to validate a custom username and password only for demo purposes. If the custom username and password does not match then it should display an error: "Incorrect user ID or password. Please type the correct user ID and password, and try again."

```
Username: user@lc.com
Password: 12345
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
    var sEmail = $('#username').val();
    if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
      $('.error-msg.username').show();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
      $('.error-msg.username').hide();
    } else {
      $('.error-msg.username').show();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  
  $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
    if ($('#password').val().length === 0) { //if password field is empty           
      $('.error-msg.password').show();
    }
    if ($('#password').val().length) { //if password has value      
      $('.error-msg.password').hide();
    }
  });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
  var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
  if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.error-msg {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="error-msg username">
    Please enter your user ID in email format (name@domain.com).
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg password">
    Please enter your password.
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg up-error">
    Incorrect user ID or password. <br> Please type the correct user ID and password, and try again.
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">USER NAME</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id='btnValidate' class="btn btn-block btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
</div>
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/86nrq2wu/22/)**

Comment: Do you have a question about this, or are you encountering some problems with implementing your requirements? At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request.

Comment: You want to validate a fixed username and password only?

Comment: @bhanusengar, Yes, I need fixed username and password, I have done validation for USERNAME & PASSWORD already if you check in JSFIDDLE if without typing anything in the field you click on SIGN IN it displays error. And now  I am trying to apply condition about custom username and password.

Comment: check this is that you want http://jsfiddle.net/86nrq2wu/23/

Comment: @YaseenAhmad, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Please update your code to this.
It will definitely work**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
            $('.error-msg.password').hide();
        $('.error-msg.username').hide();
        $('.error-msg.up-error').hide();
        $('.succ-msg').hide();
            var sEmail = $.trim($('#username').val());
        var password = $.trim($('#password').val());
            if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) { //if password field isempty 
          $('.error-msg.username').show();
        }else if($('#password').val().length === 0){
          if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
                            $('.error-msg.password').show();
          }else{
            $('.error-msg.username').show();
          }

        }else{
            if(sEmail=='user@lc.com' && password=='12345'){
                            $('.succ-msg').show();
            }else{
             $('.error-msg.up-error').show();
            }
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.form {padding: 50px 100px;}
.error-msg {display: none; color: red;}
.succ-msg {display: none; color: green;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="error-msg username">
    Please enter your user ID in email format (name@domain.com).
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg password">
    Please enter your password.
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg up-error">
    Incorrect user ID or password. <br>
    Please type the correct user ID and password, and try again.
  </div>
  <div class="succ-msg">
    Valid login details
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">USER NAME</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id='btnValidate' class="btn btn-block btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it, Thanks a lot @Bhanu

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `e.preventDefault();` with `return.false;` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

please review the following example code hope it will work for you. as i solve that on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86nrq2wu/23/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#username').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length === 0) {
            $('.error-msg.username').show();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            $('.error-msg.username').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.error-msg.username').show();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
        if ($('#password').val().length !== 0 && $('#password').val() === '12345') { //if password field
          $('.error-msg.password').hide();
        } else if ($('#password').val().length === 0) { //if password has value      
          $('.error-msg.password').show();
        } else if ($('#password').val().length !== '12345') {
         $('.error-msg.up-error').show();
        }
    });
    
    
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.form {padding: 50px 100px;}
.error-msg {display: none; color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="error-msg username">
    Please enter your user ID in email format (name@domain.com).
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg password">
    Please enter your password.
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg up-error">
    Incorrect user ID or password. <br>
    Please type the correct user ID and password, and try again.
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">USER NAME</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id='btnValidate' class="btn btn-block btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
</div>
```